# A bumpy ride on a bike?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, projectile

While riding a bike at a higher velocity, I go over the speed breakers (Hump)
I get jumped over the bike for a certain height. How do I calculate this height of jump with respect to the seat of the bike?

Comment: Depends on: your speed, the height and shape of the speed bump, the elastic properties of your saddle, the size and shape of your bike, your tire pressure, and a zillion other factors...

Comment: Most importantly, your reflex after the hump will matter. Physics can just predict how some bike with a dummy sitting on it would move after the hump. If you are riding the bike, you'll exert some random force, which is the most unpredictable.

Comment: It really depends on the tire and suspension properties mostly.

Comment: And if someone is taking video or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're riding at some speed $v$ "as the crow flies," then the vertical velocity of the bike is also proportional to $v$, and so is the speed at which your butt gets launched off the seat. Once you're in the air, your center of mass has $v^2\propto gy$, so the height of the jump is proportional to $v^2$.

Similarly, the mechanical strains experienced by the bike and your body are proportional to $v^2$. This is probably why long-distance running can actually be less damaging to your body than shorter distances; see "Running 100 miles? It may be easier on your body to go 200," http://articles.latimes.com/2013/jun/27/news/la-sn-ultra-marathon-20130627

As Johannes points out, the calculation of the proportionality constants in these relationships is going to be extremely complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the height of your body measured with respect to the seat of the bike (OP's question), does not necessarily satisfy a $v^2 \propto g y$ scaling behavior. (At low speeds you will typically stay seated, while above a critical speed you will move out of your seat.)

Comment: doesn't it depend on the height and angle of inclination of hump ?

Comment: You could have hit the jackpot by using a slightly different phrase: "as the Crowell flies". :)

Comment: Why do you say that vertical velocity is proportional to $v$? I would expect it to be a rather nonlinear dependence.